# A characterization for a complex matrix $A$ to be a normal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Today, I saw a discussion on normal matrices in this forum.

A complex $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is called normal if
$$
A^\star A = A A^\star
$$

An important characterization for normal matrices is given as follows:

"A complex $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is normal if and only if there exists a diagonal matrix $S$ and an unitary matrix $U$ such that $A = U S U^\star$."

I attempted a proof for this result. (I mostly work with real matrices!)

Suppose that a complex $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is normal. By the Schur decomposition theorem,
$$
A = U S U^\star \tag{1}
$$
where $U$ is an unitary matrix and $S$ is the Schur form of $A$, which is an upper-triangular matrix.

We can rewrite (1) as
$$
S = U^\star A U \tag{2}
$$

It is easy to verify that
$$
S^\star S = U^\star (A^\star A) U \tag{3}
$$
and
$$
S S^\star = U^\star (A A^\star) U \tag{4}
$$

Since $A^\star A = A A^\star$, it is immediate from (3) and (4) that
$$
S^\star S = S S^\star
$$

Hence, $S$ is normal.

A standard result in linear algebra is that *an upper triangular normal matrix is diagonal*.

Hence, $S$ must be diagonal.

This proves one way of the characterization.

Next, for the converse:

If there exists a diagonal matrix $S$ and an unitary matrix $U$ such that $A = U S U^\star$, then $A$ is normal.

Basically, we have to show that $A^\star A = A A^\star$.

Since $S$ is diagonal, $S$ is normal, i.e.
$$
S^\star S = S S^\star
$$

A simple calculation gives
$$
A^\star A = (U S U^\star)^\star (U S U^\star) = U (S^\star S) U^\star
$$
and
$$
A A^\star = (U S U^\star) (U S U^\star) = U (S S^\star) U^\star
$$

Since $S^\star S = S S^\star$, $A^\star A = A A^\star$.

This shows that $A$ is normal.

This is one way of establishing the characterization.

I like to confirm that this proof is all right. (I mostly work with real matrices and their real Schur forms, so I like to check here). I also like to know if there are other ways of proving the same characterization for (complex) normal matrices. Thanks!

Comment: Assume $v$ is an eigenvector of $A.$ If $A$ is normal then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^*$. This implies that the orthogonal complement of $v, $ is invariant for $A$ and $A^*.$ This orthogonal complement is a subspace of codimension $1.$ You can continue by looking for an eigenvector in the subspace, etc. In this way you get $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors. The matrix $A$ is diagonal with respect to these vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. Once you use Schur's theorem to reduce to the case where $A$ is upper triangular, the claim "A standard result in linear algebra is that an upper triangular normal matrix is diagonal." is the whole proof.

Another way of proof is to write $A$ uniquely as $A = B + iC$, where $B$ and $C$ are self adjoint. Since $A$ is normal, it can be easily shown that $BC = CB$. This implies that the eigenspaces of $C$ are invariant under $B$. Using this, just as in the proof of the diagonalization of self-adjoint matrices, one can use the fundamental theorem of algebra and mathematical induction to show that there is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that simultaneously diagonalizes $B$ and $C$. This basis diagonalizes $A$.